# how to get animation automatically on loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i want to make images effect automatically when the page loads. Right now i am using this code 
js

```
$(window).ready(function(){
$(pin).click(function(){
  $("#pin01").show().animate({left: '650px'});
})
});
```

and html

```
<p id="pin">Click me</p>
<img src="mission.gif" id="pin01" style=" display:none;position:absolute;top:300px;left:300px" />
```

When i click the button animation occurs. How can i make it possible to do animation automatically after page load without any button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put the animate line within the ready or load handler depending on your exact needs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pin01").show().animate({left: '650px'});
});
```

or

```
$(widnow).load(function(){
    $("#pin01").show().animate({left: '650px'});
});
```

The `document.ready` event occurs when the HTML document is loaded and `DOM` is ready. The `window onload` event occurs when the `DOM` is ready as well as all frames, images, etc have been loaded.

Comment: @SinghRajputKushagra, dont forget to mark an answer as correct by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This can guide future readers of this post

Answer (score 1):

You can try trigger as well:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  $('#pin').click(function(){ //<-- note the correction, it was `$(pin)` before
    $("#pin01").show().animate({left: '650px'});
  }).trigger('click'); //<-- triggers event
});
```